# smooth page scrolling infinity requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve smooth page scrolling how ever i feel like this implementation will effect performance since i'm using infinity requestAnimationFrame, my question is is there is any better solution to my implantation ? or the whole code is just bad and cannot be fixed ?

**update**
i'm just trying to achieve whole page smooth scrolling not anchor link

like those website for example

https://www.aristidebenoist.com/

http://www.thibaudallie.com/

```js
const body = document.body,
    scrollWrap = document.getElementsByClassName("smooth-scroll-wrapper")[0],
    height = scrollWrap.getBoundingClientRect().height - 1,
    speed = 0.04;
var offset = 0;

body.style.height = Math.floor(height) + "px";

function smoothScroll() {

    offset += (window.pageYOffset - offset) * speed;
    var scroll = "translateY(-" + offset + "px) translateZ(0)";
    scrollWrap.style.transform = scroll;
    callScroll = requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll);
}

smoothScroll();
```

```css
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #161616;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Neue Machina";
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.smooth-scroll-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="smooth-scroll-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam excepturi tenetur sapiente 
    dolor deleniti. Fuga labore pariatur esse. Repudiandae,voluptates nisi soluta architecto 
    inventore hic. Omnis eos expedita sed architecto illum mollitia! Totam aperiam 
    velconsequuntur a, ipsum sapiente sit laborum exercitationem distinctio labore praesentium 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The JavaScript of this [site](https://www.aristidebenoist.com/) is minified and there's no external JS files either. In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61606052/2813224) -- if you hit the "S" key it will smooth scroll when user scrolls, you'll need to adjust the direction values, ATM they are 3000 and -3000

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Added a key and scroll handler functions:

```
 window.addEventListener('keydown', smoothScroll);
 window.addEventListener('wheel', fastScroller, {passive: true});
```

Press the <kbd>D</kbd> key to scroll down
Press the <kbd>U</kbd> key to scroll up
Keep either <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>U</kbd> key pressed to continue to scroll (not so much for Chrome)
Press the <kbd>S</kbd> key to bind the window to the wheel event*
Press the <kbd>X</kbd> key to unbind the window to the wheel event
* <sup>when window is bound to the wheel event, smooth scrolling automatically scrolls in the direction to which the user
   rolls the mouse wheel</sup>

---

Here's a simple CSS property:

```
:root {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
```

[`scroll-behavior: smooth`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-behavior/)

---

#### Demo

**Note:** View demo in full page mode.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', smoothScroll);

function smoothScroll(event) {
  let direction = event.key.toLowerCase() === 'd' ? 1000 : event.key.toLowerCase() === 'u' ? -1000 : 0;
  if (event.key.toLowerCase() === 's') {
    window.addEventListener('wheel', fastScroller, {passive: true});
  } else if (event.key.toLowerCase() === 'x') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', fastScroller, {passive: true});
    }, 1000);
  }
  window.scrollBy({
    top: direction,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}

let prevST = 0;

function fastScroller(event) {
  const ST = window.scrollY;
  let direction = ST > prevST ? 3000 : -3000;
  prevST = ST;
  window.scrollBy({
    top: direction,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
:root {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
section {text-align:center;height: 100vh;font-size:5rem;border:5px solid #000;}
section::before {content: attr(id);}
a {display:inline-block; font-size: 5rem; color: gold}
a::before {content: attr(href);}
#I {background: blue;}
#II {background: red;}
#III {background: grey;}
#IV {background: green;}
#V {background: black; color: white}
#VI a {color: black;}
#VII {background: chocolate;}
#VIII {background: yellow;}
#VIII a {color: black;}
#IX {background: purple; color: white;}
#X {background: maroon; color: white;}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id='I'>
    <a href='#II'></a>
    <a class='bottom' href='#X'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='II'>
    <a href='#III'></a>
    <a href='#VI'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='III'>
    <a href='#IV'></a>
    <a href='#VIII'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='IV'>
    <a href='#V'></a>
    <a href='#VII'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='V'>
    <a href='#VI'></a>
    <a href='#I'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='VI'>
    <a href='#VII'></a>
    <a href='#X'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='VII'>
    <a href='#VIII'></a>
    <a href='#V'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='VIII'>
    <a href='#IX'></a>
    <a href='#IV'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='IX'>
    <a href='#X'></a>
    <a href='#VII'></a>
  </section>
  <section id='X'>
    <a class='top' href='#I'></a>
    <a href='#VI'></a>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: You could also just go
`* { scroll-behavior: smooth; }`